# Fade out UINavigationBarController.navigationBar?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'd like to have my `navigationBar` fade out along with my status bar and setting `animated:` to `YES` does not work, since it just animates the `navigationBar` up. I have tried the following:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
CATransition *_navigationAnimation = nil;
[CATransaction begin];
_navigationAnimation = [CATransition animation];
_navigationAnimation.type = kCATransitionFade;
_navigationAnimation.duration = 0.5;
[[self.navigationController.navigationBar layer] addAnimation:_navigationAnimation forKey:@"kNavigationBarAnimationKey"];
[CATransaction commit];
```